Question About Shopping cart session logic in flutter
Currently I am developing the flutter e-commerce app . In that add the logic to add the items to the cart for that I get the items from the product page and added in the cartpage. But once I navigate back from cart page to product page that items are available in the cart but ,when I again navigate back to any other page and again visit the cart page ,the cart gets empty. And also I want to give access to the cart from home page also so that products which are added in the cart are displayed when I click the option of cart on the home page.this is my question , how I manage the cartitems store session in whole project.
I tried by shared preference and I want the result by shared preference

What state-management approach are you using? What navigator are you using? Do you want the data only locally or on a server? Provide more information.

I want to store data locally on the device

I think to manage the cart items you can store session using shared preferences in your Flutter e-commerce app. You can write a service class where you can handle that like this way:
class CartService {
  static const _key = 'cart_items';

  /// Here save the cart items to shared preferences
  static Future<void> saveCartItems(List<CartItem> cartItems) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final jsonList = cartItems.map((item) => item.toJson()).toList();
    await prefs.setString(_key, json.encode(jsonList));
  }

  /// Here retrieve the cart items from shared preferences
  static Future<List<CartItem>> getCartItems() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final jsonString = prefs.getString(_key);
    if (jsonString != null) {
      final jsonList = json.decode(jsonString) as List<dynamic>;
      return jsonList.map((json) => CartItem.fromJson(json)).toList();
    }
    return [];
  }
}

I consider the data of your cart as CartItem Model which I am saving and retreiving.
